# Why does using Opt+Esc copy the selected text to the clipboard? How can I disable that?

Tags: keyboard, copy-paste, voiceover

I can invoke the text-to-speech engine using selecting any given text and then doing <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. However, rather annoyingly, doing so seems to copy the selected text to the clipboard, as if I did <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. If I am using Safari, I can bypass this by selecting the text and then using right-click > **Speech** > **Start Speaking**. But many apps that have text such as Firefox and others do not have this option. But the keyboard shortcut can be used with any text in any app.

So how can I make using the keyboard shortcut not also copy the text to the clipboard?